# An empty Assembly Attribute element

Tags: c#

My application has some assemblies. I've decided to write a proxy class for it. It loads assembly attributes in its constructor and stores them in readonly fields.

It works something like this:

```
public class AssemblyInfo
{
    private readonly Assembly ActiveAssembly;
    private readonly AssemblyName ActiveAssemblyName;
    public AssemblyInfo()
    {
        ActiveAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        ActiveAssemblyName = ActiveAssembly.GetName();
        FileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(ActiveAssembly.Location);
        if (ActiveAssembly != null)
        {
            Title = this.GetAttributeByType<AssemblyTitleAttribute>().Title;
        }
    }
    public readonly string Title;
}
```

And, in an another assembly:

```
sealed class CurrentAssemblyInfo : AssemblyInfo
{
}
```

It works fine, but I have a problem with GetAttributeByType function. Currently it's written this way:

```
private T GetAttributeByType<T>() where T : Attribute
{
    object[] customAttributes = ActiveAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);
    if ((customAttributes != null) && (customAttributes.Length > 0))
        return ((T)customAttributes[0]);
    return null;
}
```

It works fine (and saves a lot of place). But if nothing is found, I return null and that doesn't work fine if such an attribute isn't find.

Is there any way to return something like a "empty object" for these Attribute classes. I've checked MSDN. but it looks like all of these Assembly*Attribute classes doesn't have even empty constructor.

Comment: @flq default(T) should be null for a class!?!

Comment: Why not just check if the return value is null, and decide then what to do if the attribute does not exist? (in the example choose if title should be "", null, the filename, ...

Comment: @erikH I'm trying to make the code compact with templates. So, if I'll check the every property I get, I'll need a temporary variable for all of these items, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
private T GetAttributeByType<T>() where T : Attribute 
{ 
     object[] customAttributes = ActiveAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false); 
     if ((customAttributes != null) && (customAttributes.Length > 0)) 
         return ((T)customAttributes[0]); 
     return Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to change it, there was a little bug.

Comment: That would try to create an instance from the parameterless ctor. And according to Matvey there is none. Therefore a MissingMethodException will be thrown.

Comment: @erikH: You're absolutely right, unless he is using custom attributes with parameterless constructors.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to declare the help method:

```
private T GetAttributeByType < T >() where T : Attribute, new()
```

Then instead of null you can return `new T()`

EDIT:

And if the attributes has no default ctor stick to your original method and use as well:

```
private TResult GetAttributeProperty<TAttr,TResult>(TAttr attr, Func<TAttr, TResult> f) where TAttr : Attribute
{
    return (attr != null) ? f(attr) : default(TResult);         
}
```

And call it like

```
var s = GetAttributeProperty(GetAttributeByType<AssemblyTitleAttribute>(), a => a.Title);
```

But if this is more nice than the following may be discussed...

```
var attrTitle = GetAttributeByType<AssemblyTitleAttribute>();
var s = attrTitle == null : null : attrTitle.Title;
```

Comment: Attributes have no public constructors without parameters.

Comment: Then You cannot create an instance with Activator.CreateInstance either!? (as Fischermaen suggests)

Comment: Added a way to get the result with attributes without a public ctor without parameters...

Comment: It looks better. But how to connect it with the source function? Will it return the string value directly?

Comment: Is the example `s` is a `string`, so yes it returns the value directly. If it always is a string property you want to get you can make the two methods ino one... like `private string GetAttributePropertyByType<T>(Func<T,string> f) where T : Attribute` and call it like `GetAttributePropertyByType<AssemblyTitleAttribute>(a => a.Title)`. And easier default to `string.Empty` if that is what you want, when attribute is missing...